# JetBrains IDE double shift to search everywhere equivalent in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

In JetBrains IDEs like IntelliJ, when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key twice it pops up a 'Search Everywhere' dialog that you can type any keyword or class names and it lists all matches (even 3rd party classes if sources are available).

Is there any equivalent for JetBrains Search Everywhere in VS Code?
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/when-the-shift-hits-the-fan-search-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

There's the `Go to Symbol in Workspace` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Whether or not that will work for you will I think depend on whether the extension providing language support that you are using parses out symbols that you want to search for and reaches into the 3rd party libraries you want to search in.

If that doesn't work, you could use the Search View and just do text/regex searches.